# Features_extra: after enabling fe_block, no Machine Name field appears on block edit form

Tags: 6, blocks, features

I installed and enabled fe_block 6.x-1.x-dev, but when I reload one of my blocks' edit form, no machine name field appears. I tried clearing the cache; no dice.

What's missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `fe_block` module only allows exporting blocks represented in the `boxes` table — those created via the `admin/build/block/add` user interface.

Exportable blocks will have `block` as the second-to-last component of the admin URL:
[image: Screenshot showing valid exportable block URL and Machine name field]

Blocks created using, say, Views, or a module's `hook_block()` implementation, however, are not exportable using `fe_block` — it doesn't make sense to export blocks such as those, since Views provides its own export mechanism, and other module-owned blocks are already in code to begin with.

Comment: Smorkis, very educational! Thanks for the detailed response, complete with wonderfully-annotated screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a module that is in unstable version, and that's version is almost 2 years old without any work on it. So "missing" part is 2 years of maintenance, 2 years when Drupal changed and this module did not follow.

It's a good practice to avoid dev versions that are updated less than once in a month. Using dev versions updated rarer than Drupal's minor version number is asking for trouble.

Comment: <facepalm>You are so right.</facepalm> Thanks! I guess I'll have to forgo using Features on this site until it gets updated to D7.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this in drupal 6.31.
Does your user have permission to edit Features-related stuff?  (See https://drupal.org/node/520310)

(I didn't have permission to add that permission on my site, but disabling permissions by temporarily removing the check
    && user_access('administer features')
from the two lines that had it in sites/all/modules/features_extra/fe_block.module
does make the machine name UI appear when editing blocks.)

Comment: Yes, I'm using an administrator role for which all permissions are checked, including all those under the Features group. Thanks for the suggestion.